# Custom Post-to-Post with multiple parents?

Tags: custom-post-types, api

I currently have a custom post type of "Faculty" - each faculty can have zero or many custom post type "Bibliographies," and a bibliography can belong to one or more faculty.

What is the best practice for setting up this association, and more importantly, is this possible still using the API? I'm testing this with 3.4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When its about setting up Post to Post relations, I find the scribu's [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin the best out there. the plugin not only does provide the interface but also provides the API to handle the relations.

Comment: Thanks for the information - I'm currently using Posts2Posts but wasn't sure about the API part. Does it add hooks to the XML-RPC API or is it done otherwise?

Comment: You will have to hook to XML-RPC API yourself and then use the Posts 2 Posts functions from there.